# Bloc depends on unregistered type

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

Actually I am creating a favorite movie app which is similar to a note app which allows users to save their favorite movie name and category in an app
Actually  I am using StreamSubscription in a bloc but when I run build runner I am getting this warning

> [MovieWatcherBloc] depends on unregistered type
> [StreamSubscription<(Either<(NoteFailure, KtList<(Mlist)>)>)>] from
> dart:async
>
> Did you forget to annotate the above class(s) or their implementation
> with @injectable? or add the right environment keys?

Now I am giving the code containing MovieWatcherBloc

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:app_3/Domain/auth/notes/i_movie_repository.dart';
import 'package:app_3/Domain/auth/notes/list.dart';
import 'package:app_3/Domain/auth/notes/note_failure.dart';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
//import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart';
import 'package:kt_dart/kt.dart';

part 'movie_watcher_event.dart';
part 'movie_watcher_state.dart';
part 'movie_watcher_bloc.freezed.dart';

@injectable
class MovieWatcherBloc extends Bloc<MovieWatcherEvent, MovieWatcherState> {
  final INoteRepository _noteRepository;
  StreamSubscription<Either<NoteFailure, KtList<Mlist>>>
      _noteStreamSubscription;

  MovieWatcherBloc(this._noteRepository, this._noteStreamSubscription)
      : super(const MovieWatcherState.initial()) {
    @override
    Stream<MovieWatcherState> mapEventToState(
      MovieWatcherEvent event,
    ) async* {
      yield* event.map(watchAllstarted: (e) async* {
        yield const MovieWatcherState.loadInProgress();
        await _noteStreamSubscription.cancel();
        _noteStreamSubscription = _noteRepository.watchAll().listen(
            (failureOrNotes) =>
                add(MovieWatcherEvent.moviesReceived(failureOrNotes)));
      }, watchUncompletedstarted: (e) async* {
        yield const MovieWatcherState.loadInProgress();
        await _noteStreamSubscription.cancel();
        _noteStreamSubscription = _noteRepository.watchUncompleted().listen(
            (failureOrNotes) =>
                add(MovieWatcherEvent.moviesReceived(failureOrNotes)));
      }, moviesReceived: (e) async* {
        yield e.failureOrNotes.fold((f) => MovieWatcherState.loadFailure(f),
            (lists) => MovieWatcherState.loadSuccess(lists));
      });
    }
  }
  @override
  Future<void> close() async {
    await _noteStreamSubscription.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

And when I run it I get this error

> Object/factory with type StreamSubscription<Either<NoteFailure,
> KtList>> is not registered inside GetIt.  (Did you accidentally
> do GetIt sl=GetIt.instance(); instead of GetIt sl=GetIt.instance; Did
> you forget to register it?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't need to be instantiated in the constructor, mark it as nullable and remove _noteStreamSubscription from the constructor.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:app_3/Domain/auth/notes/i_movie_repository.dart';
import 'package:app_3/Domain/auth/notes/list.dart';
import 'package:app_3/Domain/auth/notes/note_failure.dart';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
//import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart';
import 'package:kt_dart/kt.dart';

part 'movie_watcher_event.dart';
part 'movie_watcher_state.dart';
part 'movie_watcher_bloc.freezed.dart';

@injectable
class MovieWatcherBloc extends Bloc<MovieWatcherEvent, MovieWatcherState> {
    final INoteRepository _noteRepository;
    StreamSubscription<Either<NoteFailure, KtList<Mlist>>>?
            _noteStreamSubscription;

    MovieWatcherBloc(this._noteRepository)
      : super(const MovieWatcherState.initial()) {
        @override
        Stream<MovieWatcherState> mapEventToState(
                MovieWatcherEvent event,
    ) async* {
                yield* event.map(watchAllstarted: (e) async* {
                yield const MovieWatcherState.loadInProgress();
        await _noteStreamSubscription.cancel();
        _noteStreamSubscription = _noteRepository.watchAll().listen(
                (failureOrNotes) =>
                add(MovieWatcherEvent.moviesReceived(failureOrNotes)));
      }, watchUncompletedstarted: (e) async* {
                yield const MovieWatcherState.loadInProgress();
        await _noteStreamSubscription.cancel();
        _noteStreamSubscription = _noteRepository.watchUncompleted().listen(
                (failureOrNotes) =>
                add(MovieWatcherEvent.moviesReceived(failureOrNotes)));
      }, moviesReceived: (e) async* {
                yield e.failureOrNotes.fold((f) => MovieWatcherState.loadFailure(f),
                (lists) => MovieWatcherState.loadSuccess(lists));
      });
    }
    }
    @override
    Future<void> close() async {
        await _noteStreamSubscription?.cancel();
        return super.close();
    }
}
```